# Drawing in a jpanel located in a frame with windowbuilder in java

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, graph, windowbuilder

I want to draw a simple line in a jpanel using paintcomponents and I know how to do it manually by having a class for the jpanel and another one for the frame and then making objects and the line , for example:

```
package progGUI;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class drawpanel extends JPanel {

public void paintComponent( Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponents(g);
    this.setBackground(Color.CYAN);

    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.drawLine(21, 20, 60, 60);
  }

}
```

and for the frame class

```
frame.add(drawpanel);
package paneltest;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class main extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    pan1 pan = new pan1();
    frame.add(pan);
    frame.setVisible(true);

  }

}
```

but now I'm using windowbuilder in eclipse to make GUI program that gets a expression from the user and after getting the values and ranges of variables, draws the graph of that expression .right now I'm testing simple drawings in a frame like in the link below :
[Grapher](https://www.dropbox.com/s/43mp1axdzxx0wsp/Screenshot%202015-02-11%2023.17.45.png?dl=0)

the problem I'm having is that when I make the frame , panel and other graphical components with windowbuilder ,it arranges the codes in a way that I can't implement the paintcomponent in the code . how can I solve this problem?

This is the code that I've made with windowbuilder :

```
package progGUI;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class CanvasFrame extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {

                CanvasFrame frame = new CanvasFrame();
                frame.setVisible(true);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public CanvasFrame() {
    setTitle("Graph");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 700, 542);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    JSlider slider = new JSlider();
    slider.setPaintTicks(true);


    JLabel lblEnteredExpression = new JLabel("Entered Expression");

    JLabel lblVaraibles = new JLabel("Variables");

    JFormattedTextField formattedTextField = new JFormattedTextField();

    JFormattedTextField formattedTextField_1 = new JFormattedTextField();

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    GroupLayout gl_contentPane = new GroupLayout(contentPane);
    gl_contentPane.setHorizontalGroup(
        gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(panel, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 453, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 51, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(lblEnteredExpression, Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(lblVaraibles)
                    .addComponent(formattedTextField, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 119, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(formattedTextField_1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 123, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(57))
            .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(22)
                .addComponent(slider, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 454, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(214, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    gl_contentPane.setVerticalGroup(
        gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING)
            .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(18)
                .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(lblEnteredExpression)
                        .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(formattedTextField_1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 22, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(lblVaraibles)
                        .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(formattedTextField, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 20, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addComponent(panel, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 350, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(35)
                .addComponent(slider, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(385))
    );
    contentPane.setLayout(gl_contentPane);
  } 

}
```

Comment: I'd be surprised if WindowBuilder wouldn't allow you to include custom components. If not, you could manually add your paint panel within the code

Comment: It does allow you to do that as I said but it arranges them in a way that I can't figure out how to use paintcomponent method
thats why I asked the question and put the code to find how should I change it

Comment: Assuming you have a custom component to start with, have you tried dragging into WindowBuilder?  If not, I'd either add a empty `JPanel` to Window Builder where  you want your paint component to be, set it's layout to `BorderLayout` and then add your paint component to it...

Comment: I have added the panel and my component is the same paintComponent I've written in the first example 
I just don't know how exactly should I do what I did in the first two classes in a single class which I've put It's codes in the question

Comment: Well I assume either "JPanel panel = new JPanel();" should be replaced with a reference to your drawPanel or your drawPanel should be added to it...